# Authenticating a self-signed certificate for LDAPS connection

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I want to make a secure ldap connection(ldaps) from a Linux(Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux) client to a Windows 2012 server, to change user passwords in active directory, through php.
For that, I've created a self-signed certificate(using Windows Server Manager) on the server, but when I try to connect, I get the following error(by turning debugging option on: 
`ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);`):

```
ldap_create                                                                 
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)                                 
ldap_bind_s                                                                 
ldap_simple_bind_s                                                          
ldap_sasl_bind_s                                                            
ldap_sasl_bind                                                              
ldap_send_initial_request                                                   
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0                                                   
ldap_int_open_connection                                                    
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:636                               
ldap_new_socket: 3                                                          
ldap_prepare_socket: 3                                                      
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:636                            
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0                                     
TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x42)                                  
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).                                   
ldap_err2string                                                             
PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server
```

It seems the client is not able to trust the certificate since it's self-signed.

What steps should I take to make a secure connection? The client side certificates are stored in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Comment: Do you need to trust the server's certificate and perform checks or does only encryption matter ?
What is the content of your ldap.conf file ?

Comment: Just the line `TLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell the LDAP client to ignore untrusted certificates. You can do so by adding the following to your ldap.conf file:

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

This solution is not the preferred one though. You should add the required CA root to your client and ensure that the certificate is correctly generated with the server's name in it (and if my memory serves me right the complete CA chain) otherwise nothing would stop someone to perform a MITM attack.

Comment: I'd be glad if you could help me in figuring out how do I add the CA root and ensure the correctness of certificate.

Comment: I haven't done that in years, so I cannot really help you on the detailed steps to do that, but take a look [this entry on datacenteroverlords](http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/), it helped me back then. Make sure to read the comments as well they are resourceful.

Comment: Thanks for that.Um, one more query, ldap_mod_replace() only works once on a username, the next time, it returns an error saying `res_errno: 53, res_error: <0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A129B, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0`

Comment: Either you specified a non-existent / protected attribute or you changed the username || password tuple and your connection to the ldap server is no longer valid (in which case you need to start a new one).

Comment: That is resolved. My new password was not matching the criteria. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Your LDAP server is using a self-signed certificate so, in order to trust that, the LDAP client needs the certificate for the CA that created that cert.

1. Put your CA's certificate file in `/etc/ldap/certs/myca.pem` (you may have to `mkdir` the certs directory).
2. Add a new line with `TLS_CACERT /etc/ldap/certs/myca.pem` to `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`. (You may see a similar line with "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt".)

   ```
   $ php -a
   Interactive mode enabled
   php > ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
   ...
   ldap_init: using /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
   ...
   php > $conn = ldap_connect("your_ldap_server");
   php > ldap_start_tls($conn);
   ```

Without the configuration change, you'd see `PHP Warning:  ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Connect error in php shell code on line 1`. The comments for the [function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php) provide further reading but everyone seems to go straight at setting "TLS_REQCERT never". Working != secure. `demand` is the default setting and I'd leave it that way (or explicitly set that). The documentation on TLS_REQCERT is [here](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/tls.html#Client%20Configuration). (It also appears that if you do set "never" but follow with a later "TLS_CACERT" line, it ignores the never. Ugh.)

*Note:* I know you used "ldaps://" and ldap_bind(), but try the [preferred](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-openldap-connections-using-starttls#ldap-over-ssl-vs-ldap-with-starttls) ldap_start_tls().

> STARTTLS is an alternative approach that is now the preferred method
>   of encrypting an LDAP connection.

Answer (score 2):

For those that stumble across this, PHP7.1 now allows you to set the CA file and CA directory via `ldap_set_option()` rather than having to update a server configuration file.

See the documentation for `ldap_set_option` here, paying attention to the `LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_` options: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-set-option.php

One caveat: It seems there may be a bug where `LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE` is only accepted when `LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR` is also set, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73558. I haven't verified this yet.